# Angular Button Click Registering on Both the Button and Div Underneath

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Whenever I click on my #dropDown button, it functions as intended and opens the dropdown menu; however, the click also hits the  underneath which is also clickable. I don't want the button click event to also hit the div underneath, as that is not the intended function.

```html
<ul #postCard *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" [class.selected]="getSelected() == i || currPost == post" (click)="setSelected(i)" (click)="setPost(post)" id="jobcard" class="postcard menu px-8 py-4 my-4 mx-4 bg-white border-gray border hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800">
            <li class="menu-title">
              <div class="flex flex-row items-stretch justify-between relative">
                    <h2 class="text-2xl">{{post.title}}</h2>
                    <div class="flex flex-col right-0 absolute" [style.display]="'block'">
                      <h2 id="dateofjob" class="text-lg justify-self-end justify-end justify-items-end block">{{post.date_of_job}}</h2>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex flex-row relative">
                <div>
                  <h2 class="mt-4 text-lg font-light">Description:</h2>
                  <p>{{post.care_description}}</p>
                </div>
                <p id="timeofjob" class="font-light justify-self-end justify-end justify-items-end inline right-0 absolute">Start: {{post.start_time}} | End: {{post.end_time}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="flex items-center justify-start w-full">
                <div class="relative inline-block w-full">
                    <button #dropDown (click)="toggleDropdown()" class="dropdownbutton mt-2 relative z-10 block p-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-transparent rounded-md dark:text-white focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-40 dark:focus:ring-opacity-40 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring dark:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-800 dark:text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>

                    <div *ngIf="shown" class="absolute left-0 z-20 w-full py-2 mt-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow-xl dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <h2 class="block px-4 py-3 text-gray-800">Your Application: </h2><a class="block px-4 py-3 text-sm text-gray-800 capitalize transition-colors duration-200 transform dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white"> {{post.applications[0].message}} </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the event are bubbling, both the clicks on the button and the div get registered. We can tell our function to stop further propagation of the current event by using `event.stopPropagation()`

In your, capture the $event in your function as a parameter `HTML`

```html
 <button #dropDown (click)="toggleDropdown($event)" class="dropdownbutton mt-2 relative z-10 block p-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-transparent rounded-md dark:text-white focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-40 dark:focus:ring-opacity-40 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring dark:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none">
 <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-800 dark:text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

and then in your `.ts` component, use that event to stop further bubbling of events, so that the div click won't be called:

```js
toggleDropdown($event: Event):void {
  $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using stopPropagation in the click function.

check out this link for more details:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e/